# Rally: drag drop multi cards in board

Tags: drag-and-drop, rally, google-cardboard, multiple-choice

I create an rally taskboard app by using the following source code: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/taskboard

Anyone know to drag drop multi task cards by one times?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the drag and drop features on rally components (grids, boards) are single item operations.  I don't think there is anyway to do multi drag and drop.